# <span> Close button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote a script for closing my div, so when i click on the x the div is deleted but for some reason when i click the x the whole page is deleted. Does any know where i might have gone wrong.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="note">  
         <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>x</span>    
    <div class="note-editable">
        <p>Hi and welcome to</p>
        <p1>Stickynote</p1>
        <p2>Go ahead and note away</p2>
    </div>        
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete .note div or .note-editable div?

Comment: what you want to remove? `.note` div?

Comment: please provide full code snipet

Comment: just use `this.parentNode.remove()` check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h1y3phq0/

Comment: i am trying to delete .note div

Comment: Your javascript is targeting the `body`, that's why the whole page is removed. Should be this: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLdya58a/)

Comment: This will not be extendable in the future research js event delegation so any note in the future can be removed via the x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you went up one level too far. Try

```
onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);'
```

Comment: This can be shortened quite a bit by using @Sushil's comment above, there's no reason to do that much traversing.

Answer (score 0):

The parent of your `<span>` is `<div class="note">`, whose parent is presumably the `<body>`, which would have a parent of `<html>`. So, when you do:

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
```

You are referencing the `<html>` tag, and when you remove:

```
this.parentNode.parentNode
```

you are removing the `<body>` from your `<html>`, thus removing all of your content.

Instead, to achieve your desired result, you could remove one `parentNode` reference in your example, like this:

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
```

or instead just use:

```
this.parentNode.remove();
```